# Is the use of carousels good? Do users actually know how to use a carousel?

Tags: responsive-design, usability-study, carousel, multiple-screens

The question is pretty much what is on the title. I keep having the feeling that building a multiscreen (responsive/adaptative) environment with carousels is something that the users don't know how to use.

The designs vary so much across sites (dots, arrows, auto, etc) that it seems to be a very bad practice. But I'm wondering as there probably is already scientif research around this subject, if there is a global understanding of "you should use or you shouldn't use carousels"?

Comment: http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/ Refer to this. Usually I will not recommend Carousel for any website.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate because the linked question is pretty comprehensive, but if there is a separate specific question around carousel use that you have (such as whether to use dots, arrows etc for navigation as you sort of mention here) then that's something different and may warrant a separate question. If that is the case then you can [edit] your question to focus more on the specific issue you want resolving. Otherwise I think the linked question should cover off most of your concerns.